# how does the Grammarly Windows Software detect text in any window or software?

Tags: windows, architecture, software-design, grammarly

In the new update of Grammarly, I saw that it works on any window. Unlike their office extension, this one makes me curious about how it works. [How it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uF8x4.png)
I suggest that it acts as an intermediate software between HID devices and the textboxes. I don't know deeper about programming. Can anyone explain that?

Comment: I'm curious about it too. Did you find out how it works?